# Where did SDK7 go?

Tags: 13.04, sdk

I installed from Oracle SDK 7 but it did not say the path of the SDK.How can i find that where did the SDK go?I must set JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You could do an exhaustive search for "java"...

```
$ cd /; find . -name 'java' 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from P J Singh's solution(in which you may have to parse through a long list of files), if you have installed java, and can run using `javac` and `java` commands, you should be able to fetch the location of the binary using `which javac` and `which java`. This will give you the location of the binary file. If, by JAVA_HOME, you mean the location of the `jre`, it is `/usr/`.

Comment: Jobin, good suggestion.  I would try this first.  An exhaustive search may be needed if Java was installed by uncompressing and copying the required files to some (unknown) directory, in which case java or javac would not show up using the "which" command.